# What happened to the "aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types" strict aliasing rule?

Tags: c++, struct, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

Previously, in basic.lval, there was this bullet point:

> an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or contained union),

In the current [draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11), it is gone.

There is some background information at WG21's site: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1359r0.html#2051:

> The aliasing rules of 7.2.1 [basic.lval] paragraph 10 were adapted from C with additions for C++. However, a number of the points either do not apply or are subsumed by other points. For example, the provision for aggregate and union types is needed in C for struct assignment, which in C++ is done via constructors and assignment operators in C++, not by accessing the complete object.

Can anyone explain to me, what this means? What has this strict aliasing rule to do with struct assignment in C?

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) says about this rule:

> These bullets describe situations that cannot arise in C++

I don't understand, why it is true. For example,

```
struct Foo {
    float x;
};

float y;
float z = reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(&y)->x;
```

The last line seems to do what the bullet point describes. It accesses `y` (a `float`) through an aggregate, which includes a `float` (member `x`).

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: The first bullet point never made much sense anyway (in either language) so I'm glad to see it gone!

Comment: @M.M could you explain the "in either language" claim?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer in C or C++

Comment: @M.M I mean why it does not make sense in C

Comment: @LanguageLawyer say you have `struct S { int a; float b; };` and `float *c = malloc(100);` and int and float are the same size and no padding; then `c[0] = c[1] = 0; S s = *(S *)c;` is not an aliasing violation according to that text, because the `float` `c[0]` is accessed by an aggregate type that has a `float` as its member  (never mind the fact that the offset of the member doesn't correspond to the memory being accessed)

Comment: @M.M: If one assumes that a compiler that can see that an lvalue is derived from another will treat an access to the former (for purposes of N1570 6.5p7) as though made using the latter, then an access `myUnion.member1` would *be* an access to `myUnion`, which would be a struct union which contains `myUnion.member2`, and thus such an access would be allowed to modify the stored value of the latter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lvalue you use to access the stored value of `y` is not `*reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(&y)`, of type `Foo`, but it is `reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(&y)->x`, which has the type `float`. Accessing a `float` using an lvalue of type `float` is fine. In C++, you can not "access the value of a union or struct" (as whole), you can only access individual members. The rationale you quoted points to a difference between C and C++:

```
  struct X { int a, b; };
  struct X v1 = {1, 2}, v2;
  v2 = v1;
```

In C, the standard says that the assignment loads the value of `v1` (as whole) to assign it to `v2`. Here the values of the objects `v1.a` and `v2.b` (both have types `int`) are accessed using an lvalue of type `struct X` (which is *not* `int`).

In C++, the standard says that the assignment calls the compiler generated assignment operator which is equivalent to

```
struct X {
   ...
   struct X& operator=(const struct X&other)
   {
       a = other.a;
       b = other.b;
   }
};
```

In this case, *calling* the assignment operator does not access any value, because the RHS is passed by reference. And executing the assignment operator accesses the two `int` fields separately (which is fine, even without the aggregate rule), so this is again not accessing a value through an lvalue of type `struct X`.

Comment: What would the rule say in circumstances where storage received from `malloc` is written using one PODS and read with another that has the same layout?

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I think an unwritten assumption in the question is that `A.B` "accesses" `A` (and so `P->B` "accesses" `*P`). I don't see anything in the Standard that clearly states that's not so, but the fact that `A.B` on its own does not imply modification or lvalue-to-rvalue of anything supports it.

Comment: @supercat This rule still is OK with it. If the two types are layout-compatible, the individual members are layout-compatible. If they are layout-compatible, accessing members from one POD type through a pointer to a different POD type is covered by an earlier bullet in the "aliasing clause".

Comment: @MichaelKarcher: From what I can tell, neither gcc nor clang supports such usage.  What's needed to make the C rule work is recognition that an access via pointer which is visibly derived from an lvalue should be considered as an access to that lvalue, but gcc doesn't support that usage either.

Comment: What if `Foo` is `struct Foo { char c; float x; };`? Can't we say that in `float z = reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(&y)->x;` we access `y`  through an lvalue of type `float` and so this is fine, too?

Comment: No, it's not fine. There is no float object at `reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(&y)->x`, so this access is undefined behaviour. But it's not the rule discussed in this question that forbids it.

Comment: `float y; reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(&y)->x` is finally fixed in https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2535.html

Comment: thats a strange cwg issue actually, since `int i = 0; int j = reinterpret_cast<C&>(i).m;` is well defined (as well as `float y; reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(&y)->x`) as its shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50383187/is-it-a-strict-aliasing-violation-to-alias-a-struct-as-its-first-member). They have probably changed the wording for the UB they put in the example