# casting between 2 layout compatible types

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

I'm a quite confused about whether or not it's possible to cast an object of a certain type to another type with the same layout. I am aware that supposedly similar questions have been posted on Stack Overflow but some are answered in the negative, while others are not, answers given based on different parts of the standard, which adds to the confusion. For example:

**(1)** [Can you reinterpret_cast between types which have the same representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595488/can-you-reinterpret-cast-between-types-which-have-the-same-representation?noredirect=1&lq=1) **-> answers NO**
**(2)** [Safety of casting between pointers of two identical classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762929/safety-of-casting-between-pointers-of-two-identical-classes) **-> answers YES**

And so I'd like to clarify, on the one hand, the specifications of the standard that state what is feasible and what leads to undefined behavior, but also, and above all, the consequences that such practice may have from the compiler's point of view (I'm thinking, for example, about strict aliasing rules and type-based optimizations).

Assuming 2 structs `A` and `B` with the same standard layout:

```
struct A { int i; float x; }
struct B [ int j; float y; }
```

Both **(1)** and **(2)** accepted answers state that casting an object of type `A` to type `B` is legal:

```
A a { 1, 2.3 };
auto& b = reinterpret_cast<B&>(a);  // ok
```

However, **(1)** states that trying to access any member of `a` trough reference `b` is undefined behavior, violating the strict aliasing rules. (The answer does, however, mention a part of the standard that has since been updated and no longer seems appropriate to confirm the author's answer, if it ever was.)

While **(2)** states that it is perfectly legal, since both structures have the same standard layout.

```
auto ai = b.j;  // UB for (1) while OK for (2)
```

So who's right here ? and :

- If **(1)** is right, which part of the standard states that accessing `a.i` via `b.j` is UB ? What is the risk of such a practice from the compiler's point of view (assuming strict aliasing is enabled) ? (A detailed description of what could happen would be appreciated.)
- If **(2)** is right, at least for the C++11 standard, is it still right for C++17 and above ? Is there any risk that some compilers assume that `b` cannot be modified through `a` considering strict aliasing rules ?

Comment: "*If (1) is right, which part of the standard states that accessing a.i via b.j is UB ?*" You just cited it.

Comment: It should be noted that your answer #2 is *not* talking about what operations the standard *requires* to be legal. What it's citing is that, due to layout compatibility requirements, it would be very difficult for implementations to make your code not do the obvious. It does not claim that such accesses are fine with regard to strict aliasing. Indeed, the question asks "can I reliably count on this pointer conversion working as expected in every case" not "does the standard require that this works".

Comment: @Nicol to your 1st comment: as far as I understand C++20 Standard, §7.2.1 item 11, I am not accessing `a` as a whole, I am accessing individual member `a.i` (which is int) from `b.i` (which is int too), so not UB.

Comment: @Nicol to your 2nd comment: this is true that the question is related to reliability, not standard; the answer, however, mentions standard statements which suposedly prove that this is not UB.

Comment: No, it proves that the *layout* is reliable, not that the *access* is legit.

Comment: @Nicol: that's right, and this is the purpose of my question: what rule of the standard, Ben Voigt may have missed, states that the access is not legit; making answer of (2) a wrong answer.

Comment: I think [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) gives reasons for legal conversions taking account of cases where type aliasing rules deny some reasons.

Comment: @shrike: Clang and gcc have a mode which is blind to the possibility that taking a pointer that might identify a structure of one type, converting it to a pointer to a 
layout-compatible type, and dereferencing it to access a member thereof, might affect a structure of the original type.  They also have a mode which allows arbitrary type punning.  What the Standard says is irrelevant.