# P1359R0 [basic.lval] wording change and aliasing rules

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

The [N4778](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4778.pdf) draft (2018) of the C++ standard contains the following section:

> 7.2.1 [basic.lval]
>
> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - **the dynamic type of the object**,
> - a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type similar (as defined in 7.5) to the dynamic type of the object,
> - **a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object**,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic typeof the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or contained union),
> - a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
> - **a `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std::byte` type**.

However, the [draft at eel.is/c++draft/](http://eel.is/c++draft/#expr) [lists](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval) only 3 bullets (I highlighted the common ones):

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue whose type is not similar ([conv.qual]) to one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - **the dynamic type of the object**,
> - **a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object**,
> - **a `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std​::​byte` type**.

[P1359R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1359r0.html#2051_Simplifying_alias_rules) explains the change:

> The aliasing rules of [basic.lval] were adapted from C with additions for C++. However, a number of the points either do not apply or are subsumed by other points. For example, the provision for aggregate and union types is needed in C for struct assignment, which in C++ is done via constructors and assignment operators in C++, not by accessing the complete object. ... It has been suggested that the aliasing rules should be extended to permit an object of an enumeration with a fixed underlying type to alias an object with that underlying type.

Could you please explain in layman's terms the practical consequences of this wording change? As far as I understand, `enum class E : T { ... };` is suggested to allow to alias `T`. Is this correct? Will anything else besides this become defined/undefined?

Comment: Seems like you've covered the specific changes made, and the rationale, quite well in the question. Not sure what I could add.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0, so the only practical change is that `enum` can alias the underlying type?

Comment: Not sure where you're getting the `enum` change from. From my reading of the quoted passage, that's just something people are _suggesting_. And my reading of the first part of it is that there should not be any practical change because this is an editorial/clean-up operation for redundant/pointless rules. Perhaps someone else can go into more detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happened to the "aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types" strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878519/what-happened-to-the-aggregate-or-union-type-that-includes-one-of-the-aforement)

Comment: An object has a dynamic type?

Comment: @curiousguy, if class `D` is derived from `B`, and `b` has type `B*`, then `*b` has static type `B`, but can have dynamic type `D`.

Comment: @curiousguy You know that "dynamic type of an object" wording is defective, don't you?

Comment: @Evg For polymorphic objects or for any derived class?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Would there be any non-political problem with abandoning the notion that PODS have a dynamic type or a lifetime separate from their container, but replacing it with rules based on code structure, saying that in most cases where code forms a pointer to some storage and then uses an lvalue based upon it to access an object, operations using that storage via that pointer/lvalue will generally be unsequenced with regard to anything else that happens between the formation and use of the pointer, and then recognizing cases that would imply sequencing?

Comment: @supercat Not sure I understand what you mean. I don't think there is a problem with abandoning "dynamic types" for objects. "dynamic type" is a property of expressions. Widespread usage of "dynamic type" as a property of an object is  defective.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: The problem would be that abandoning the concept and recognizing that it should never have existed would cause the Standard to unambiguously define the behavior of many programs which some compiler maintainers have for years insisted were "broken", and would make it obvious that it was the compilers, rather than the programs they refuse to process, that were defective.

Comment: @supercat Hard to understand which programs you mean without examples.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Type-based aliasing optimizations are based upon the notion of storage having a "dynamic type".  If a compiler is given something like `{ if (*intptr) *floatptr=1.0f; return *intptr;}`, the "reason" the compiler is allowed to ignore the possibility of `*floatptr` accessing `*intptr` is that if it did so, it would set the dynamic type of `*intptr` to `float`, and an object whose dynamic type is `float` can't be accessed via `int`.  A better rule would say that if storage is accessed twice using some type, it must not be accessed via another type in the interim *unless*...

Comment: ...there is an intervening action which would associate the lvalue used for the intervening access with the type of the earlier and later ones.  I think the authors of C89 thought it sufficiently obvious that compilers should recognize common intervening actions that they didn't need to make allowances for them.  Thus, there's nothing in any version of the C Standard that would allow for even a construct as commonplace as `someStruct.intArray[i]=3;` to access an object of structure type using an lvalue of type `int`.

Comment: @supercat Aren't you confusing "dynamic type" with "effective type"?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: The "effective type" is a C notion; "dynamic type", as applied to PODS, is the C++ equivalent (it has other meaning for non-PODS types).

Comment: @supercat I don't think "dynamic type" is equivalent (one can't change it like "effective type" etc.). And that it applies to PODs. The C++ Standard seem to use "dynamic type" with different meaning in different contexts (and rarely, if ever, as it is defined). One of the meaning is type of polymorphic object "dynamically changing" during construction/destruction. But objects of polymorphic types aren't POD.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: As far as I can tell, the rules in the C and C++ Standards are confusing because there has never been a consensus as to what they're supposed to mean.  When they were first written, the Committees expected that compilers would try to process programs usefully in cases where doing otherwise would be silly, even the Standard would allow such silly behavior; committee members were thus willing to agree to rules which didn't provide for everything programmers needed to do, because they expected that compilers would support necessary behaviors anyway.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Since then, there has been a need to have more precise rules, but any clear rules would disagree with someone's idea of what the rules are supposed to mean, and thus the only rules that can achieve consensus are those which are so vague that they can "agree" with contradictory ideas about what they're supposed to mean.

Comment: @supercat IUC the fact that the current C compilers value TBAA over possibility of effective type change is considered to be inconsistent with the standard. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1796r0.pdf#subsection.2.11

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: The way N1570 is written, it can mean almost anything depending upon what is meant by the words "object" and the phrase "by an lvalue...".  If one interprets the word "by" literally, all assignment operators invoke UB, since the object identified by the left-hand operand is not written by an lvalue expression, but by an assignment expression that (in C) is not an lvalue.  If one interprets "by an lvalue..." as "by something having a recognizable relationship with an lvalue...", that would work, but clang and gcc refuse to recognize relationships that aren't mandated.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: If one were to recognize that the "object" in the first part of N1570 refers only to objects used in a particular "context" [see below], and "by" means "by an lvalue that, within that same context, has established a fresh relationship with an object of one of the following types", that would handle most practical programs that otherwise require `-fno-strict-aliasing`, while allowing most useful optimizations.  Compilers could draw the context widely or narrowly, provided that the any particular use of the first context above be balanced by an equally broad use of the second.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Are you aware of anything in the Standard that would clarify what is meant by the words "object" and "by" in N1570 6.5p7 sufficiently to avoid making most of the language [like the ability to use assignment expressions, or to use arrays within structures] unavailable to strictly conforming programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no practical consequences.

This is a housekeeping clean-up to remove redundant/unused rules inherited from C (or older C++ standards). It doesn't quite meet the criteria of "editorial" because it's not just tinkering with grammar/spelling/formatting, but it's not a semantics change either.

The `enum`-related change you mention didn't happen; it's just a suggestion, mentioned in an "additional note" within the issue description. We could see this happen in future. Personally, I think that would be a good idea.

Comment: I don't think it is really editorially, given that it is listed [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/n4812.html) not in the section about editorial changes. Could still have no effect though.

Comment: @walnut Well, granted, perhaps "editorial" isn't _quite_ the right official word but you know what I mean :)

Comment: In C, if one recognizes that when code forms the address of an aggregate member and then accesses storage via that address, such an access effectively employs the aggregate type, then allowing member objects to be accessed via the parent object is necessary to make things work.  How does C++ handle accesses to aggregate members?

Comment: @supercat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0: You're saying this is a clean-up which doesn't affect anything, but one of the clauses which is stricken would be essential in the C Standard; if the C++ Standard is different in a way that would make the clause redundant, I think it would be good to actually say what that difference is in your answer.

Comment: @supercat I am not going to enumerate the differences between C and C++ in an answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0: What clause in the C++ Standard, other than the stricken one, would allow an assignment to a struct-type lvalue to be used to modify the objects therein?  If this is merely an editorial clean-up, there should be some other clause that renders the stricken text redundant, and I think your answer would benefit from identifying what that clause is.

Comment: @supercat Thanks for your feedback. At the moment, I'm done with this answer. Feel free to write your own if you have more information to add.

Comment: @supercat Or read https://stackoverflow.com/a/56878686/560648