# what's the meaning of [basic.lvalue]/8.6?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>        [8.1] the dynamic type of the object,
>        [8.2] a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
>        ...
>        [8.6] **an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or contained union)**,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct Test{
    float b;
    int a;
    char c;
};
int main(){
  int data = 0;
  int r = reinterpret_­cast<Test*>(&data)->a; //#1
}
```

Is the intent of bullet point 8.6 to cover this example?But ,I think itselft is legal,because the type of glvalue `reinterpret_­cast<Test*>(&d)->a` is `int` and the dynamic type of object `data` is `int` ,so the bullet point [8.1] is enough to cover this example. I haven't found a example for bullet point [8.6].somebody could give a example for [8.6]

Comment: _"Is the intent of bullet point 8.6 to cover this example?"_ No. _"But ,I think itselft is legal"_ No.

Comment: [basic.lval]/8.6 had no meaning and has been removed [What happened to the “aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types” strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878519/what-happened-to-the-aggregate-or-union-type-that-includes-one-of-the-aforement) [P1359R0 \[basic.lval\] wording change and aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59603620/p1359r0-basic-lval-wording-change-and-aliasing-rules)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer  why,how do you interpret these questions?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer  yes,please note the tag,we discuss these questions under **c++17**

Comment: It never had any meaning. Even when existed in C++98/03/11/14/17.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer what your meaning is ,there are no any example assiociated with bullet point 8.6 in c++17 standard?

Comment: Yes. You can't invent a code example where 8.6 would be applicable. Please read the answer to the first question I've linked above.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer yes,I think I have got your idea,since exists the constructors or assignment operators of  class type,hence the access of object only occured on scalar type,Is right?

Comment: _"hence the access of object only occured on scalar type,Is right?"_ Right.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer However,I think the sentence ` int r = reinterpret_­cast<Test*>(&d)->a;` is valid.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ref#4.2 says (about `E1.E2`): _"If `E2` is a non-static data member … the expression designates the named member of the object designated by the first expression."_ `data` doesn't have any named members. So, you have UB.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I think E1 now here is `*reinterpret_­cast<Test*>(&data)` rather than `data`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211686/discussion-between-language-lawyer-and-jack-x).