# upcast and strict aliasing rule from C++20

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, c++20, strict-aliasing

As per C++17 standard, §6.10 item 8:

> 8 If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object
> through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the
> behavior is undefined:
> (8.1) — the dynamic type of the object,
> ...
> (8.7) — a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
> (8.8) — a char, unsigned char, or std::byte type.

I understand that both downcast (8.1) and upcast (8.7) do respect strict aliasing rule. Is this correct ? So, the following code should be legitimate; right ?

```
struct A { int x = 1; };
struct B : A { int y = 2; };
B bb;
A* ab = &bb;
auto x = static_cast<A&>(bb).x;  // ok
auto y = static_cast<B*>(ab)->y; // ok
```

Now, reading the C++20 Standard, §7.2.1 item 11 (I only have the draft, though), I am surprised that point (8.7) relating to the type of the object's base class has simply disappeared !

> 11 If a program attempts to access (3.1) the stored value of an object
> through a glvalue whose type is not similar (7.3.5) to one of the
> following types the behavior is undefined:
> (11.1) — the dynamic type of the object,
> (11.2) — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object, or
> (11.3) — a char, unsigned char, or std::byte type.

I find it hard to imagine that upcast violates the rule from C++20 onwards. Does it ? If not, what rule in the standard states that it does not ?

---

**EDIT**:

My question has been marked as duplicate of [What happened to the "aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types" strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878519/what-happened-to-the-aggregate-or-union-type-that-includes-one-of-the-aforement)

Well, this is true that the other question answers why 8.4 to 8.8 disappeared from C++17 §6.10, however it does not answer my 2nd question:

What rule of the standard states that accessing an object through a base type of its class does not violate strict aliasing ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: I'm trying to understand the relationship between my question and the one it's pointed out as duplicate. So, dereferencing a pointer is not accessing the value, right ? So, if I have `struct A { int x; }` and `struct B { int y; }`, then accessing member `x` of an `A` through `reinterpret_cast<B&>(A()).y` is not violating the strict aliasing rule ?

Comment: https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2535.html (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878519/what-happened-to-the-aggregate-or-union-type-that-includes-one-of-the-aforement#comment135836054_56878686)

Comment: For clarification of the duplicate: It answer your question why the item from the list has been removed. However, your code example has nothing to do with it anyway. The aliasing rule is relevant when you have a pointer/glvalue that has expression type (pointer to) `X`, but the result of the expression refers to an object of some other type `Y`.

Comment: When you do `static_cast`, then the result is of the same type as the expression type indicates (or the cast has undefined behavior already if the downcast is invalid). `ab` is a pointer to the `A` base class subobject of `bb`, `static_cast<A&>(bb)` is a glvalue to the same subobject and `static_cast<B*>(ab)` is a pointer to the `bb` object. You get the situation where expression type and object type mismatch and aliasing rules may be relevant only with `reinterpret_cast` (and even then there are exceptions for pointer-interconvertible objects).

Comment: For example `reinterpret_cast<A&>(bb)` is a glvalue expression with type `A`, but refers to a `B` object and so `reinterpret_cast<A&>(bb).x` has UB by resolution of the CWG issue mentioned above, although aliasing still doesn't apply because it applies only to _access_ (of scalar objects) which a member access expression is not (and which why the item in the list didn't have any meaning). But `static_cast<A&>(bb).x` is valid, since it actually results in member access on the base class subobject of type `A`.

Comment: _What rule of the standard states that accessing an object through a base type of its class does not violate strict aliasing?_ Please read the Note in the paragraph you cite: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lval#note-10. See also http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.access#sentence-2